# Write a CSV file in quoteMode NON_NUMERIC, to have only strings and non numeric cells surrounded by quotes

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a CSV to write that has that schema :

```
StructType s = schema.add("codeCommuneCR", StringType, false);
s = s.add("nomCommuneCR", StringType, false);
s = s.add("populationCR", IntegerType, false);
s = s.add("resultatComptable", IntegerType, false);
```

If I don't provide an option "*quoteMode*" or even if I set it to `NON_NUMERIC`, this way :

```
ds.coalesce(1).write().mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
.option("header", "true")
.option("quoteMode", "NON_NUMERIC")
.option("quote", "\"")
.csv("./target/out_200071470.csv");
```

the CSV written by `Spark` is this one :

```
codeCommuneCR,nomCommuneCR,populationCR,resultatComptable
03142,LENAX,267,43
```

If I set an option "*quoteAll*" instead, like that :

```
ds.coalesce(1).write().mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
.option("header", "true")
.option("quoteAll", true)
.option("quote", "\"")
.csv("./target/out_200071470.csv");
```

it generates :

```
codeCommuneCR,nomCommuneCR,populationCR,resultatComptable
"03142","LENAX","267","43"
```

But I would like `.option("quoteMode", "NON_NUMERIC")` to generate :

```
codeCommuneCR,nomCommuneCR,populationCR,resultatComptable
"03142","LENAX",267,43
```

according to my schema.

How should my settings be done ?

Regards,

Comment: Could be a bug. Consider filing a report at issues.apache.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've opened an issue about it, and learnt that `Spark` handles now the CSV through `Univocity`, who do not support anymore this feature.

Re-adding it is not planned, the `"quoteMode"` option is no more taken into account.

Comment: How come it's unplanned? I can't find any other way to differentiate between empty strings and nulls in CSV with Spark.

Comment: The `emptyValue` and the `nullValue` options of the DataFrameWriter should help differentiate between empty strings and nulls.